# Galois Correspondence as it relates to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

### **Tl;dr**

Before getting into the details, let me just give a summary of the main source of my confusion. Basically, I currently believe the following list of statements are true:

1. The extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$ is Galois
2. Every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$ can be written as $k_0 + k_1 \sqrt{2} + k_2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}} + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ with $k_i \in \mathbb{Q}$
3. The automorphisms $\alpha$ of the extension are the four automorphisms defined by mapping $\sqrt{2}$ to $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ to $\pm \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$
4. The set of members of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$ of the form $k_0 + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ is not a field despite the fact that it is fixed by a subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}))$

However, my reasoning below makes me to believe that at least one of these statements is not true, but I can't figure out which one it is. So my question boils down to, which one of these assumptions is wrong? If none of them are wrong, then what is wrong with the reasoning below?

### Context

So, my understanding of the Galois Correspondence is that if $L/K$ is some Galois extension (i.e. seperable, and splits some polynomial in $K[x]$), and $G$ is some subgroup of $Aut(L/K)$, then the set of members of $L$ fixed by $G$ is a subextension of $L/K$.

Furthermore, any finite extension $L/K$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $K$. The Galois Automorphisms of $L/K$ being the automorphisms which are both field automorphisms and vector space automorphisms of $L/K$.

So, applying this to the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$, this can be thought of as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we can write any member $x$ of this field as

$$x = k_0 + k_1 \sqrt{2} + k_2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}} + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$$

With $k_0, k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\alpha$ be a galois automorphism in $Aut(L/K)$, then

$$\alpha(x) = k_0 + k_1 \alpha(\sqrt{2}) + k_2 \alpha(\sqrt{2})\alpha(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}) + k_3\alpha(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$$

Now, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$ can be created algebraically via adjoining a root of $x^2 - 2$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ resulting in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and then adjoining a root of $x^2 - (1 + \sqrt{2})$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ resulting in this tower

$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$$

The point being that $\alpha$ above is defined via a decision to  map $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ and a decision to map $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ to $-\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$. Meaning there are 4 such automorphisms, and this makes sense since the degree of the extension is 4 and this extension is Galois. But let us choose the automorphism which sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ but fixes $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$.

I.e.

$$\alpha(x) = k_0 - k_1 \sqrt{2} - k_2 \sqrt{2}\alpha(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}) + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$$

This automorphism together with the identity automorphism forms a subgroup of $Aut(L/K)$, but the only elements fixed by this subgroup are of the form

$$k_0 + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$$

But this is not a field, as there is no inverse of $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ of the form $k_0 + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ with $k_0, k_3 \in \mathbb{Q}$

So, something is wrong in my reasoning above, although I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: 3 (assuming 1) is dubious: if an automorphism maps $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$, then it should map $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ to $\pm \sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}}$. And even 1 is unclear: your number field $K$ has an embedding into $\mathbb{R}$. But consider the polynomial $(X^2-1)^2-2=X^4-2X^2-1$. Then $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ is a root of it, and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree at least $4$ (it’s not equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$) so it’s irreducible. But $i/x$ is also a root of the polynomial so is in $K$, thus $i \in K$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you remind me why $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ isn’t in the field? I’m having a hard time seeing this

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for that, so, I think I see your reasoning for why 1 is not necessarilly true. 

Are you saying that $$L_0 \subset L_1 \subset L_2$$ and $L_1/L_0$ is galois, and $L_2/L_1$ is galois, then it is not necessarily the case that $L_2/L_0$ is galois? 



The first sentence is somewhat unconvincing to me, I am not sure why $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ should be mapped to $\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Its a bit hard to describe succinctly, but basically, just assume there is an inverse of the form $k_0 + k_3\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ and then multiply it by $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$. I am pretty sure there is no way to make it 1 with $k_0$ and $k_3$ being in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @WilliamOliver field automorphisms U have the property $U(x^a) = U(x)^a$. So in Mark’s example $U(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ must descend the square root and flip the sign. The intuition for this is to look at a being an integer. example we let $a =2$ then  $U(x^a) = U(x^2) = U(x*x) = U(x)*U(x) = U(x)^2$. Square roots are just raising to the exponent $\frac{1}{2}$ so the same property holds. The rest is easy to see via distributivity of addition.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I definitely see why this would be true for integers, but I fail to see a way to prove that this would work for non integer powers. It seems somewhat un-intuitive that it would work that way.

Comment: I’m not sure how to prove it off hand but the proof must be similar to why linear operators/functions L obey $Lcx = cLx$ when c is a constant and x is something acted on by the linear operator. The same hand waiving of $L(2x) = L(x+x) = L(x) + L(x) = 2L(x)$ is used in the intuition and works for any integer, but for non integers the situation is clearly more complicated in the same way that this automorphism property seems like a logical jump. I’ll think about it some more

Comment: Ah here’s a way forward, if we might know nothing about $U(x^{\frac{1}{2}})$ but we do know $U(x)^a = U(x^a)$ if $a$ is an integer. So we can conclude: $U(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 = U((x^{\frac{1}{2}})^2) = U(x)$ and therefore $U(x^{\frac{1}{2}}) = U(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ this technique lets you cover all rational $a$. I don’t think “real valued $a$” will be tractable this way, but it satisfies your needs at least

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Ahh I see, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @WilliamOliver: yes, if $M/L$ is Galois and $L/K$ is Galois, $M/K$ need not be Galois. For my second sentence, let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $K$ mapping $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$. Let $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$, then $\sigma(x)^2 = \sigma(x^2)=\sigma(1+\sqrt{2})=1-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What Mindlack said. I guess we might want to add that $p(x)=x^4-2x^2-1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ because
$$p(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+4x^2-2$$ is irreducible by Eisenstein. The extension is not Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$ because it contains a zero of $p(x)$, but does not contain all of them (the non-real zeros are obviously missing). In other words, the extension is not normal over $\Bbb{Q}$.